# Adding multiple XNamespaces into an XDocument

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-namespaces

I am trying to create a GPX serializer using the XDocument from Linq. At the beginning of the document I should specify 3 XML namespaces, to achieve something like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<gpx version="1.1" creator="TrekBuddy 0.9.99" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:nmea="http://trekbuddy.net/2009/01/gpx/nmea" xmlns:gsm="http://trekbuddy.net/2009/01/gpx/gsm">
  <trk>
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="48.926513616" lon="19.650097458">
        <ele>1787.0</ele>
        <time>2010-08-12T13:47:17.214Z</time>
        <fix>3d</fix>
        <sat>6</sat>
        <extensions>
          <nmea:course>263.8</nmea:course>
          <nmea:speed>1.2</nmea:speed>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
```

I am using the following code for XDocument instantiation:

```
private XDocument CreateXDocument(Gpx.Gpx data)
{
    XNamespace xmlns = data.XmlnsUrl;
    XNamespace nmea = data.NmeaUrl;
    XNamespace gsm = data.GsmUrl;
    return new XDocument(
        new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null),
        new XElement(xmlns + "gpx",
            new XAttribute("creator", data.Creator),
            new XAttribute(nmea + "nmea", data.NmeaUrl),
            new XAttribute(gsm + "gsm", data.GsmUrl),
            CreateTrk(data.Track, nmea)));
}
```

And this code for adding individual extensions:

```
private XElement CreateExtension(Extension extension, XNamespace nmeaNamespace)
{
    if (extension is NmeaExtension)
    {
        var nmea = extension as NmeaExtension;
        return new XElement("extensions",
            new XElement(nmea + "course", nmea.Course),
            new XElement(nmea + "speed", nmea.Speed));
    }
    else return new XElement("extensions");
}
```

However, instead of the expected result, I get the following:

```
<gpx creator="TrekBuddy 0.9.99" p1:nmea="http://trekbuddy.net/2009/01/gpx/nmea" p2:gsm="http://trekbuddy.net/2009/01/gpx/gsm" xmlns:p2="http://trekbuddy.net/2009/01/gpx/gsm" xmlns:p1="http://trekbuddy.net/2009/01/gpx/nmea" xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1">
  <trk xmlns="">
    <trkseg>
      <trkpt lat="4909.933" lon="2016.67883">
        <ele>1787.0</ele>
        <time>2010-08-12T13:47:17.214Z</time>
        <fix>3d</fix>
        <sat>6</sat>
        <extensions>
          <Geolocation.Gpx.Extensions.NmeaExtensioncourse>188.6</Geolocation.Gpx.Extensions.NmeaExtensioncourse>
          <Geolocation.Gpx.Extensions.NmeaExtensionspeed>0.9774523</Geolocation.Gpx.Extensions.NmeaExtensionspeed>
        </extensions>
      </trkpt>
```

Can somebody help me to adjust my code, so I get the expected result? The [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnamespace(v=vs.110).aspx) is not particularely helpful in this case...

Comment: Don't put a prefix on your attributes. This is rarely needed. You don't need to declare the namespaces, Linq2Xml will do that for you if you use them. Make sure the elements generated by CreateTrk use the namespace.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] for your problem?  Without definitions for `Extension` and `Gpx.Gpx` it's hard for us to know what is happening.